# Why I have this error trying to use the JavaScript substr() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am absolutly new in JavaScript and I have the following problem trying to use the **substr()** method.

I have a string that represent a data: 20141202 (that is for 2014-12-02 without the '-' character).

So my **DataDA** variable contains the value **20141202**

Now I want to extract the **year**, the **month** and the **day** from this string and I have done something like this:

```
year = DataDA.substr(0,4);
```

and this seems work fine because year value is **2014**

But when I try to extract the month I have a very strange behavior, infact I do:

```
month = DataDA.substr(5,6);
```

and instead obtain **12** I obtain **202**

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: `month = DataDA.substr(4, 2)`

Comment: [FROM MDN substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) *start is a character index. The index of the first character is **0**, and the index of the last character is 1 less than the length of the string. substr() begins extracting characters at start and collects length characters (unless it reaches the end of the string first, in which case it will return fewer).*

Comment: look up the specification of `substr` function in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp and `substring` function in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument in `.substr(start[, length])` is length to extract. You can either use length as 2 to `.substr` or use `.substring` which uses index.

```js
alert("20141202".substr(4,2));
```

Answer (score 1):

First parameter is from which index are you going and second one is how much do you want to go.

So you need

```
month = DataDA.substr(4,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
function substr(start,lenght)
```

you can use like this,

```
var DataDA = 20142201;

var year = DataDA.toString().substr(0,4); 

var day = DataDA.toString().substr(4,2); 

var month = DataDA.toString().substr(6,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to:

```
 month = DataDA.substr(4,2);
```

The 1st number defines the starting number and the second defines the length of the string.